# Hazelcast - How to get the current hazelcast instance inside EntryProcessor?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I need to get the current hazelcast instance inside EntryProcessor.process method.

I need to send message to topic in process method.

How do I get the instance?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve it by implementing `HazelcastInstanceAware` interface in your `EntryProcessor` class.